# How may I put packages with options in vector?

Tags: packages, package-options

As you all know, instead of writing

```
\usepackage{package1}
\usepackage{package2}
\usepackage{package3}
```

and so on,  we may write

```
\usepackage{package1, package2, package3}
```

How may I obtain instructions equivalent with

```
\usepackage{package1}
\usepackage{package2}
\usepackage[optionA]{package3}
```

with the shorter vector notation?

Comment: The same set of options will be used by every package in the list. So this is not really possible.

Comment: If you're having trouble, maybe due to package conflicts or after package updates, the former way makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As from the comments, it is probably not possible. Moreover, it is advisable not to use the vector notation, because it makes it more difficult to debug if problems arise because of package conflicts or updates.